# Lua/torch multiplication of 1D and 2D tensors

Tags: matrix, lua, torch

I am trying to multiply two matrices in lua whose dimensions are a=40,000x1 and b=1x40,000. In Lua, the 40,000x1 matrix is showing up as a 1D tensor and the 1x40,000 matrix is showing up as a 2D tensor. Whenever, I try to multiply them simply using a*b, an error is showing up: `multiplication between 1D and 2D tensors not yet supported`. I cannot iteratively go through each index because this function is used regularly in my program and would considerably increase time of execution. How can I multiply `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [view](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#result-viewresult-tensor-sizes):

```
c = a:view(40000, 1) * b
```

Comment: Error: `expecting a contiguous tensor stack traceback`.

Comment: `a:contiguous():view(40000, 1) * b` (note: this involves a memory copy)